# How to save list value in Map in Java?

Tags: java

I am having a map of String and List of String,
this is mine string

```
Name|A|B|D
Last|C|F|G|H
```

```
Map<String , List<String>> edited = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(String s : data){
    String[] split = s.split("\\|");    
    for(int i = 1; i < split.length; i++){
        partValue.add(split[i]);
    }
    edited.put(split[0], partValue);
    partValue.clear();
}
```

when partValue is clear after second for loop then the map list value size also become 0.I don't want map list value to be affected.

I was trying to store

Name -> ["A", "B", "D"]

Last -> ["C", "F", "G", "H"]

Comment: Where are you instantiating `partValue`? Bring that inside the for loop instead of clearing

Comment: Don't re-use `partValue`. Create a new list for each item.

Comment: _In general_, don't reuse objects that aren't supposed to be "the same thing".

Answer (score 0):

Don't reuse `partValue` but always create new one per line for every entry in `edited` map..

```java
Map<String , List<String>> edited = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(String s : data){
    String[] split = s.split("\\|"); 

    // Always initialize new list for every line
    List<String> partValue = new ArrayList<>(split.size() - 1);
   
    for(int i = 1; i < split.length; i++){
        partValue.add(split[i]);
    }

    edited.put(split[0], partValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `edited` map contains a reference to the `partValue` list, clearing it will also lead to the removal of the list elements you previously added (but the reference will still be there in the map). So, this will lead to incorrect results.
You can try something like:

```
    edited.put(split[0], partValue);
    partValue = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can simplify your loops, too:

```
        for (String s : data) {
            String[] split = s.split("\\|");
            List<String> partValue = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
            edited.put(partValue.remove(0), partValue);
        }
```

Comment: But in exchange for worse performance as you are converting array to immutable list, then to `ArrayList` and then shifting whole `ArrayList` to the left by one.

Comment: That is true, yes

Comment: It was nearly there .. try `edited.put(split[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length)`

Comment: Yes, I think that's better